# Bash Script error using grep

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I have the following script

```
var1=$(pwd)
echo $var1
if [ -e $var1 ]  
 then
  echo present directory exists
   if [ grep ^d\* | $(ls -al) ] 
    then
      echo these are the directories in $var1
   fi
else 
  echo failed
fi
```

Running this script gives the following output with errors

```
/home/user1/Desktop/workspace
present directory exists
ifelse.sh: 6: [: missing ]
ifelse.sh: 6: ifelse.sh: total: not found
```

Please explain the errors. 
If possible give a resource where I can learn about about Bash script errors completely. Thanq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your grep.

You must interpolate (execute) the grep and pipe then evaluate the exit code of that command overall:

```
if [ $(grep ^d\* | $(ls -al)) ]
```